# How to drop Or Disable Sql Server Login Trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

How to disable sql server 2008 Login trigger even if logon trigger make rollback any user and DAC Option is Disabled ??

Answer (score 1):

Start the server in maintenance (single user) mode with `-m`.